# How to remove element from collection at child control level

Tags: wpf, binding, parent-child, observablecollection, itemscontrol

I've created UserControl for adding/removing attributes using the buttons. It has ItemsControl with ObservableCollection of attributes bound to it as a ViewModel and button for adding new attribute to collection. Each new attribute creates an entity in collection which is also a UserControl with bound attribute ViewModel and button for deleting itself.

I wanted to write this functionality so the single attribute control (and other controls) can be reusable - and I use it in a few places. Currently adding new attributes works properly, but I can't find any working way for *delete* button to work properly and remove object from the collection.

I tried to refer through *this.Parent*, but *CustomAttributeControl*'s parent is null, I tried to refer through Tag or use Prism.Core, but I couldn't implement anything properly for this to work and I couldn't find anyone with similar nested controls problem to base on. It's easy when there is no nested control for single attribute, but here I can't come up with anything. I'm fairly new to WPF and I feel there should be an easy way to do this.

[single attribute control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWmuf.png)

attribute control's XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.UI.CustomAttributeControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:xxx.ViewModels.Attributes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
  <DockPanel Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,2">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="160"/>
    <TextBlock Width="60"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="DataType" Height="20" Width="120" SelectionChanged="DataType_SelectionChanged"/>
    <TextBlock Width="10"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ListValues}" x:Name="ListValues"  Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="120"/>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Visible}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20,0"/>
      <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="X" Width="22" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20,0"/>
    </DockPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

[list control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJGyK.png)

list control's XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.UI.CustomAttributesControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx.UI"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
  <StackPanel>
    <Label FontSize="20">Custom attributes</Label>
    <StackPanel>
      <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Attribute name</Label>
        <TextBlock Width="60"/>
        <Label Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Attribute type</Label>
        <TextBlock Width="10"/>
        <Label Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">List values</Label>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <Label Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Visible</Label>
          <Label Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Delete</Label>
        </DockPanel>
      </DockPanel>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"> <!-- it's binding ObservableCollection of custom attributes from parent control -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomAttributeControl />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
      <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Margin="20,10" Click="AddAttribute">+ Add attribute</Button>
      </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code for adding attribute in .xaml.cs:

```
        private void AddAttribute(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var attributes = (ObservableCollection<CustomAttribute>)DataContext;
            attributes.Add(new CustomAttribute());
        }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Typically the parent view model would expose an ICommand property to delete an element from the child collection. The appropriate element would be passed as command parameter. Ideally, the child UserControl would expose an ICommand dependency property that would then be bound like `<local:CustomAttributeControl DeleteCommand="{Binding DataContext.DeleteElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>`.

Comment: In the child UserControl, the delete Button would also bind to that ICommand property by `<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" .../>`

Comment: It would be simpler if you wouldn't have the CustomAttributeControl child UserControl, but just an equivalent DataTemplate. Then the delete Button could directly bind its Command property to the parent view model property.

Comment: I also don't really see what your customattributecontrol is adding to the mix over a datatemplate other than complexity. I'm not sure I follow where your adding code is. If you made that a listbox rather than an itemscontrol the user could select one. You could use selecteditem to choose which one to remove. Or set issynchronisedwithcurrentitem on the listbox and the selected item would then be the current item of the default view.  So long as you know which CustomAttribute you could .Remove it from your observablecollection.